# Canvas getting cleared when adding data to store in Sencha Touch List

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, canvas, sencha-touch-2

I have a Sencha Touch  Ext.List which has one html5 canvas. Whenever I am adding any item to the store the canvas element is getting lost.

Refer this fiddle:-
https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/74i/

Is there any way to add records to Ext.List dynamically without affecting the Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of a bug in sencha touch 2.3.1 + versions. 
The workaround here is to add a refresh listener event in the Ext.List to redraw the canvas every time the store is updated.

The modified below:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {

}
});

Ext.define('Contact', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    idProperty: 'firstName',
    fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
}
});

Ext.define('Contacts', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config: {
    model: 'Contact',
    storeId: 'Contacts',
    data: [{
        firstName: 'Tommy',
        lastName: 'Maintz'
    }, {
        firstName: 'Rob',
        lastName: 'Dougan'
    }, {
        firstName: 'Ed',
        lastName: 'Spencer'
    }, {
        firstName: 'Jamie',
        lastName: 'Avins'
    }]
}
});

var store = Ext.create('Contacts');

Ext.create('Ext.List', {
fullscreen: true,
itemTpl: '<div> <div class="contact">{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong></div>' + '<div> <canvas class = "drawCanvas" id="{firstName}" width="200" height="100" "> <div>' + '</div>',
store: 'Contacts',
listeners: {
    'refresh': function(cmp) {
        console.log('calling refresh');
         var canvasArray = cmp.element.dom.getElementsByClassName('drawCanvas');
        Ext.Array.each(canvasArray, function(canvas, index) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
        });
    },
    'initialize': function(cmp) {
        console.log('calling initialize');
        cmp.getStore().on('addrecords', function(store, records, eOpts) {
            var c = document.getElementById(records[0].data.firstName);
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
        });
        var canvasArray = cmp.element.dom.getElementsByClassName('drawCanvas');
        Ext.Array.each(canvasArray, function(canvas, index) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
        });
    },
    'select': function(cmp, record, eOpts) {
        console.log('select');
        var store = cmp.getStore();
        var no = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        var name = 'te' + no;
        store.add({
            firstName: no,
            lastName: 'Maintz'
        });
        cmp.refresh();
    }
}
});
```